# WebObjects unit testing

Tags: java, eclipse, junit4, webobjects

I want to do unit tests on a framework called WebObjects using java with the IDE eclipse. I have tried to use junit and wounit. The thing is I always encounter the problem, that I cannot create a WOComponent and test its method because I don't have access to a WOContext. So my question would be if someone can give me an example different than the one found on http://hprange.github.io/wounit/usage.html of how to create a WOContext through the framework of wounit or is there a way to create it my self?

Comment: please Erika, read [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It might be better to ask on the WebObjects mailing list:  https://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/webobjects-dev

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still wanting to know, there is a WO testing framework called wounit (https://github.com/hprange/wounit) that works great for EO testing.

See Project Wonder for code that extends and supplements the official WO distribution at https://github.com/wocommunity/wonder

There is also a wiki at wocommunity.org and a slack channel. You need an invite for the slack channel but it is easy to get.